# Restrict how many forms/reports users can generate with oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, middleware, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

Is there a way to restrict how many reports users can generate? We recently had a case where few users generated about 100 reports each which in retrospect bogged up the system.

Forms/Reports version 11.1.1.2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there's a *system*-related way to do that, but - as a developer, you could:

- create a table which holds information about reports being ran. It would contain columns like (user, date, report name, ...)
- insert a row into that table in reports' After Parameter Form trigger
- delete a row from it once the report finishes in After Report trigger
- write a function that returns number of reports currently running for a specific user
- call it in Before Report trigger and - if it exceeds limit you enforce (don't hardcode it - store its value into some table), then stop report's execution and inform the user (use SRW built-in procedures to do that)

Yes, it means that you should edit all reports (RDFs) you have in order to implement those changes.